# Should a web designer know JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been doing web designing for quite some time. My question is:

Should a web designer know JQuery at all?

Thanks

Comment: Well, maybe you should first explain what you call a «WebDesigner»...

Comment: Jquery was cleverly made so that both web developers and web designers should not have trouble using/understanding it. So i think it is safe to say that jquery can be used by both parties, i don't see any arguments or subjective stuff in that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessary **but** it is good to have that weapon in your web design arsenal if you want to make your web pages full of life.

In fact, Jquery has been made such that it becomes very easy for the designers to get started with it. For example, see its selector machensim, it is pretty similar to **CSS selectors**, something designers are always used to.

For example, **[Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com)** is famous web designer and guess what he knows JQuery and he creates amazing lively pages.

Finally, have a look at this great resource:

[**jQuery for Designers**](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/)

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: Thanks and yes it was important to show that you see :)

Answer (score 5):

Most of the people I know with the job title "Web Designer" (as opposed to "Web Developer") are concerned only with *design* and not with the technical details of *implementation*.

So, for their jobs, it is important to know what jQuery can make possible (i.e. nothing that they shouldn't already know is possible from a broader understanding of what JavaScript can achieve), but not how to use it.

More knowledge is always good, but a designer would probably be better off learning more about subjects such as usability, accessibility, information architecture, colour theory and so on first.

Answer (score 1):

My personal view is that a web-designer shouldn't be expected to know how to program in jQuery. However, I do think they should:

1. Have a good awareness of what jQuery is, what it is useful for and how it can be used appropriately to enhance a site. This also means understanding what *cannot* be easily done with jQuery. Be aware of the possibilities and the limitations.
2. They should be able to integrate and style off-the-shelf plugins that don't require much more than following basic instructions.
3. A good designer must keep up with how jQuery is being used "out there" in the web, enabling them to see how it can enhance interfaces and solve common problems. Like everything in the fast-moving world of the web you need to keep on top of the trends and also be able to distinguish between fads and genuine innovation.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is about structuring content

CSS is about presenting your content

JQuery is about behavior and interaction with content

A good designer should be able to deal with challenges in all 3 areas.

Answer (score 1):

First, some traditional analogies:
Should a race car driver know how the race car engine works?
Should she know how to fix it and tune it?
Should she know how to improve the engine and design a new part for it?

The answers:
No. Not necessarily.

Could it help, in certain situations, to:

- increase productivity,
- make html and css cleaner,
- make better visual design decisions,
- make better interaction design decisions,
- better understand what is possible to design (improve creativity)

Yes. Yes definitively.

Comment: Well said, I like this answer the most!

Answer (score 1):

Web Designer should (must?) know jQuery exist. Should also know its basic capabilities so that his designs could include some cool stuff that is really easy to do with jQuery.

I wouldn't expect much more from a designer.

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't think it's a part of designing if you know its additional knowledge you have & it also helps you some other way. But i think javascript & javascript libraries are not a cup of tea of Web Designer. I think you should concentrate on CSS, HTML & if possible FLASH.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get by in the computer industry by learning as little as possible, I think you're setting yourself up for career suicide.

Given two web designers of approximately equal design ability, whom would you pick for your project? The one with Javascript knowledge or the one who doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

If a web designer is a programmer or want to be one, yes.  But if not, he/she should not learn it, separation of concerns.  I wanted to close this question, seems not a programming one, but I'm interested to read others' ideas :-)

But based on Sarfaz provided link, i think you should learn it. jQuery seems, is like the Excel Macro of web, you need to learn some Macro programming in order to spiffy up your spreadsheet(aesthetic-wise and functionality-wise), in the same vein that the best way to spiffy up your website appeal is by using jQuery